# Posting data to external form

Tags: javascript, forms, http, post

I need to post data to form on external site that is not under my control. I'm building tool to allow user to fill data on one place and then post to multiple external sites which house similar forms, rather than filling each form individually.

Basically, workflow goes like this:

1. User fills comprehensive form on my page
2. This data gets stored to my db
3. User is redirected to thank you page, with links to external forms
4. When any of the link is clicked, new window should open with form partially field with the matching fields from my form

This last step is hackish one. I'm relying on external form to be properly coded, so when I do post to it with insufficient data (captcha and few other required fields missing), I'm counting on that page to reload with posted data being incorporated in the form, and fields with missing data marked. This way, user can fill only those missing data (ideally only captcha) and not have to spend another hour reentering same data again.

This means that doing curl post won't cut it, so I went with following JS approach.

```
function repostForm(id, url) {    

var map = fieldMap[id];  // this is map between my field names and external form field names

// construct form 
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
form.setAttribute('action', url);   
form.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

for (i=0; i<map.length; i++) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('name', map[i].external);
    input.setAttribute('value', submissionData[map[i].local]);
    form.appendChild(input);
}

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

}

This code executes well and I can see data being posted to the external form. However, instead of showing me partially filled form with some field missing, I just get blank form.

I tried this with 2 different forms for now and they both act that way.

Am I unlucky enough, so that these forms have additional security checks (like checking HTTP Referer field), or am I missing something on more basic level? I cannot send link to these forms since that info may be sensitive, so I'm interested if this basic idea should work, in ideal case, if everything fits properly, or does it have some fundamental flaw.

I know there will be allot of edge cases and I'm only interested in principle.

Thanks allot in advance

Comment: They can use some kind of CSRF protection

Comment: You either build a browser plugin or you will have to face the fact there is nothing you can do. If they do not accept post requests from another domain, you are out of luck because of the same origin policy making it nearly impossible for JavaScript to interact with the other page.

Comment: Having browser plugin would make this problem a breeze, however I'm limited to PHP, JS and alike.

Answer (score 0):

'However, instead of showing me partially filled form with some field missing, I just get blank form'
Well, the serverside part still needs to display the partially filled form and if the coder of that 'post-reciever' did not code that functionality into that code, then, like everything computer-related the universal rule holds true: "If you did not tell it to do something, it wont do it."

That and things like HTTP Referer field and other tricks people use to safeguard them from external form-posts.

You COULD get away with it if your users navigate to the external sites via a proxy-server you control... hint. You could code one in php, parse the html/ecmascript (in php) (or try to regex it), set the fields in the source and send modified source to the user. It's sort of a 'man in the middle'(attack).

When using this solution, please keep in mind that this would eventually put you on hacker's radars: since the more users you have, the bigger the 'prize-pot' is of cracking your system and getting all those yummy user-data! Likewise, if 'they' manage to take-over that proxy-server (that your users trust you won't abuse), they get access to countless user-accounts of all your users!

Good luck!

Comment: This seems like something I could try, since I'm out of ideas. I'm limited to PHP + JS and accompanying technologies. I'll try to do a crude version today just as a proof of concept.